# Anyone familiar with a good "sticky windows" library for Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I want to recreate the stickiness and snapping of windows, like it is implemented in Winamp.

The basic premise is, when you drag a window and it comes close to another one, it will snap to it and will stick. When you move it the two will move together.

I need it for a MDI application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read this article and try to adopt it for your program:

[Sticky Windows - How to make your (top-level) forms to stick one to the other or to the screen](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/stickywindows.aspx)

The class presented in the article inherits from *System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow*, thus no inheritance is required in order to make your class "Stick-able".

Comment: My current implementation is using this library - we are running into lots of issues with the way it's implemented. We are looking for something else.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [magnet forms component](https://github.com/edoreshef/magnet-winforms) that also supports joint move of "glued" forms. I hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I don't know how well will it works with MDI projects.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/eugsnapformextender.aspx

Comment: Nice, but still has a few bugs. Thanks.