# Name/Term of an unknown feature

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, forms

I would like to implement a feature in my application, the problem is that I don't know where to search because I don't know the name/term of this feature.

In some applications, when you move the Form near a border/corner of the screen, the application automatically self adhering to that border until you drag the form far the border to un-adherit.

I don't have any application example to show using this feature, sorry about that.

Someone could explain me which is the name/term of this feature, and where I can find a source to examine the techniques used to implement this feature (in WinForms)?.

Comment: Do you mean like Windows 7 does?

Comment: That's sometimes called "magnetic", if you mean windows of an application snapping to each other.

Comment: @OneFineDay Thanks but I'm not sure about what you are talking, I didn't see Windows 7 shell (explorer) doing that.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, I'm not sure whether could be that, maybe yes but I can't find anything related to "magnetic" borders

Comment: Look for the term "docking".  Also, the Windows task bar could be an example.  It is an AppBar and you can create your own.

Comment: I found something interesting, is more or less like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589268/how-to-make-my-windows-form-app-snap-to-screen-edges , well, really the feature what I mean is exactly that but should be more improved, for example in other applications I've seen that when the Form is near the border it snaps without needing to drop the mouse, if someone know better example please comment it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is sometimes called 'snapping', 'sticky' or 'magnetic' windows, like used in WinAmp. An example implementation can be found at [CodeProject: A .NET Snap To Screen Form](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15314/A-NET-Snap-To-Screen-Form).

The C# version comes down to this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WINDOWPOS
{
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int cx;
    public int cy;
    public int flags;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private const int SnapOffset = 35;
    private const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 70;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING)
        {
            SnapToDesktopBorder(this, m.LParam, 0);
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private void SnapToDesktopBorder(Form clientForm, IntPtr intPtr, int widthAdjustment)
    {
        var newPosition = new WINDOWPOS();
        newPosition = (WINDOWPOS)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(intPtr, typeof(WINDOWPOS));

        if (newPosition.y == 0 || newPosition.x == 0)
        {
            return;
            // Nothing to do!
        }

        // Adjust the client size for borders and caption bar
        Rectangle ClientRect = clientForm.RectangleToScreen(clientForm.ClientRectangle);
        ClientRect.Width += (SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width * 2) - widthAdjustment;
        ClientRect.Height += (SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Height * 2) + SystemInformation.CaptionHeight;

        // Now get the screen working area (without taskbar)
        Rectangle WorkingRect = Screen.FromControl(clientForm).WorkingArea;

        // Left border
        if (newPosition.x >= WorkingRect.X - SnapOffset && newPosition.x <= WorkingRect.X + SnapOffset)
        {
            newPosition.x = WorkingRect.X;
        }

        // Get screen bounds and taskbar height
        // (when taskbar is horizontal)
        Rectangle ScreenRect = Screen.FromControl(clientForm).Bounds;
        int TaskbarHeight = ScreenRect.Height - WorkingRect.Height;

        // Top border (check if taskbar is on top
        // or bottom via WorkingRect.Y)
        if (newPosition.y >= -SnapOffset && (WorkingRect.Y > 0 && newPosition.y <= (TaskbarHeight + SnapOffset)) || (WorkingRect.Y <= 0 && newPosition.y <= (SnapOffset)))
        {
            if (TaskbarHeight > 0)
            {
                newPosition.y = WorkingRect.Y;
                // Horizontal Taskbar
            }
            else
            {
                newPosition.y = 0;
                // Vertical Taskbar
            }
        }

        // Right border
        if (newPosition.x + ClientRect.Width <= WorkingRect.Right + SnapOffset && newPosition.x + ClientRect.Width >= WorkingRect.Right - SnapOffset)
        {
            newPosition.x = WorkingRect.Right - (ClientRect.Width + SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width);
        }

        // Bottom border
        if (newPosition.y + ClientRect.Height <= WorkingRect.Bottom + SnapOffset && newPosition.y + ClientRect.Height >= WorkingRect.Bottom - SnapOffset)
        {
            newPosition.y = WorkingRect.Bottom - (ClientRect.Height + SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Height);
        }

        // Marshal it back
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(newPosition, intPtr, true);
    }
}
```

But the code seems to be a bit bloated, I think it can be greatly simplified. It also only works on desktop borders, not other windows.

See also [Anyone familiar with a good “sticky windows” library for Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110554/anyone-familiar-with-a-good-sticky-windows-library-for-winforms), both answers linking to other CodeProject solutions: [SnapFormExtender - a magnet for your MDI child forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6338/SnapFormExtender-a-magnet-for-your-MDI-child-forms) (2004) and [Sticky Windows - How to make your (top-level) forms to stick one to the other or to the screen](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6045/Sticky-Windows-How-to-make-your-top-level-forms-to), also from 2004.

Comment: I noticed that it eats the right/bottom borders of the app (the non-client area) when snapping it at the right/bottom (taskbar) edges of the screen.

Comment: Don't expect me to support it, I just report what I found. ;) It gives you an idea of how it can be done, feel free to supply fixes to CodeProject or edit this post. I guess that for example you need to do `SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width` and `Height` twice instead of once. Edit: scratch that, that is entirely the wrong property he's using, as it _"Gets the thickness, in pixels, of **the resizing border that is drawn around the perimeter of a window that is being drag resized**"_. It isn't the window chrome size, it's the grey border you see when resizing. This code is broken.

Comment: I just replaced that border measurement logic (that seems not neccessary) with `this.Width` and `this.Height`, now it works as expected, thanks for your time.